# aioredis.errors.ProtocolError: Protocol error, got "H" as reply type byte

Tags: django, redis, django-channels, channel, redis-server

I have a Django project and I'm trying to implement the Redis channel. When I add the config below, my app works.

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
    }
}
```

However, when I try to add the following config, I'm getting `aioredis.errors.ProtocolError: Protocol error, got "H" as reply type byte` error.

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Here is my consumers.py file;

```
class VideoCallSignalConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'Test-Room'
        # print(self.scope["user"])

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()
```

Btw, I'm using macOS. I already have installed Redis with `brew install redis` command and started the `redis-server` with `daphne -p 6379 VideoConference.asgi:application` command.